# I am trying to install pyaudio on Mac and getting the following error

Tags: python, xcode, gcc, pyaudio, portaudio

% pip3 install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/41/jq1tn1b113b6nmbmpqqfxhrr0000gn/T/pip-install-yuqomyva/pyaudio_df9e48fd3dc447b18c59302d7aac4fe2/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/41/jq1tn1b113b6nmbmpqqfxhrr0000gn/T/pip-install-yuqomyva/pyaudio_df9e48fd3dc447b18c59302d7aac4fe2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/41/jq1tn1b113b6nmbmpqqfxhrr0000gn/T/pip-record-kg79q2az/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyaudio
cwd: /private/var/folders/41/jq1tn1b113b6nmbmpqqfxhrr0000gn/T/pip-install-yuqomyva/pyaudio_df9e48fd3dc447b18c59302d7aac4fe2/
Complete output (16 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/src
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/src/_portaudiomodule.o
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
#include "portaudio.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/41/jq1tn1b113b6nmbmpqqfxhrr0000gn/T/pip-install-yuqomyva/pyaudio_df9e48fd3dc447b18c59302d7aac4fe2/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/41/jq1tn1b113b6nmbmpqqfxhrr0000gn/T/pip-install-yuqomyva/pyaudio_df9e48fd3dc447b18c59302d7aac4fe2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/41/jq1tn1b113b6nmbmpqqfxhrr0000gn/T/pip-record-kg79q2az/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install pipwin
```

And:

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Hope It Helps :D

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: what did you try?